# How to mockup in Java POJO calling JAX-RS Web service with @OPTIONS annotation

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I would like the use in RESTful WS @OPTION annotation to use it as a Help. I found one snippet on [http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=AIDR-master/aidr-output/src/main/java/qa/qcri/aidr/output/getdata/GetBufferedAIDRData.java](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS). There is snippet of code:

```
 @OPTIONS 
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
 @Path("/channel/filter/{crisisCode}") 
 public Response getBufferedAIDRDataPostFilter(@PathParam("crisisCode") String channelCode, 
   @QueryParam("callback") String callbackName, 
   @DefaultValue("1000") @QueryParam("count") int count) { 
  return Response.ok() 
    .allow("POST", "GET", "PUT", "UPDATE", "OPTIONS", "HEAD") 
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*") 
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true") 
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, UPDATE, OPTIONS, HEAD") 
    .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With") 
    .build(); 
 }
```

But I didnt't found, how to call and obtain content of header etc. from definition above on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the snippet that you posted in a JaxRS REST API implementation, my solution provided below is also a JaxRS Client implementation.
This can be implemented in any language using any framework though depending on your requirements.

Following is a code snippet to invoke the OPTIONS request on a REST API endpoint and process its response.

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class RestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
        WebTarget target = client.target("https://<api-base-url>/<resource-path>");

        Response response = target.request().options();
        Map<String, List<String>> headerMap = response.getStringHeaders();

        for (String key : headerMap.keySet()) {
            List<String> values = headerMap.get(key);
            for (String value : values) {
                // The header and its corresponding value can be processed as per the case.
            }
        }

        // This will return a list of all supported HTTP Methods (GET, POST, PUT, ..., etc)
        List<String> httpMethods = headerMap.get("Allow");

        for (String method : httpMethods) {
            if ("GET".equals(method)) {
                // Do something
            }

            if ("POST".equals(method)) {
                // Do something
            }
            ...
            ...
        }

        response.close();
    }
}
```

There are may more methods exposed by the Response class which can be explored as needed for your implementation.